# Creating immutable properties without boilerplate

Tags: immutability, d

I am trying to make properties for immutable fields of structs in my program but I don't like the amount of boilerplate I need to get it working.
I just want to make shure there is no shorter way.

```
struct Foo
{
    private immutable int[] bar_;
    @property immutable public immutable(int[]) bar() { return bar_;} 

    this(immutable int[] bar)
    {
        this.bar_ = bar;
    }
}

void main()
{
    immutable foo = Foo([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
    auto bar = foo.bar;
}
```

I would expect something like

```
private immutable int[] bar_;
@property public immutable(int[]) bar() { return bar_;}
```

or even in semi c# style

```
public immutable int[] bar { get; }
```

The version I currently have seems like a lot of boilerplate and verry confusing. I hope there is a shorter way of writing a 'bar()' function that I'm just not aware of.

Comment: Why is it a property in the first place? Being immutable means it can't be set anyway so no need to skip the setter...

Comment: It was more of a minimal example in this case.

Comment: I mean in ANY case, you can never set an immutable, so why not just make it a public field?

Comment: If you do not want to use the accessors library, as @jpf suggests, you can still reduce your boilerplate slightly by using `auto`, and a `public` section: `public:
@property auto bar() { return _bar; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [accessors](http://code.dlang.org/packages/accessors) library to generate the setters:

```
import accessors;

struct Foo
{
    @Read("public")
    private immutable int[] bar_;

    mixin(GenerateFieldAccessors);
}
```

However, as Adam said you usually don't need or want to use setter and getter properties for `immutable` fields.

Comment: Well, binary compatibilities between assemblies is one reason why one might want to choose properties over fields. When you have property functions, applications that depend on this assembly shouldn't have to recompile as long as the function signature doesn't change.